# Map two input streams, one graphics objects and the other characters through Show

Tags: list-manipulation, map

The question is how to sequentially execute `Show` with two streams of input. The first is graphics object stream and the second is a character stream for supplying labelling for the graphics. I tried

```
ss = {{ListPlot[x1]}, {ListPlot[x2],...};
labelling = {aa, bb, cc, dd....};
Map[Show[#1, PlotLabel->StringJoin[#2,"...", "..."]]&, {ss,labelling}]
```

I tried both `Map` and `MapThread` which give inconsistent results, i.e., works sometimes and not work some other times. It became consistent when I put the labelling elements into individual curly brackets, i.e.,

```
labelling = {{aa},{bb},{cc},(dd))
```

Wonder why is this the case?

Comment: Where do these "streams" come from? Are they simply lists? Can you show a *complete executable* example, even simple, so we can see what doesn't work and propose a fix?

Comment: Map[Show[#1, Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> StringJoin["COVID-19:", #2], 
   AxesLabel -> {"Date", "Cumulative Total"}, Joined -> False, 
   PlotRange -> All] &, {{aa, bb, cc, dd}, 
  Partition[CountyNames, 1]}] where aa,bb,cc,dd are ListPlot, DateListPlot or ErrorListPlot combined they produce a plot for dates and error bars, and CountyNames is a list of comma separated list of county names, such as Santa Clara.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not very clear. Is this what you are looking for?

```
plots = Table[ListPlot[RandomInteger[10, 10]], 4];
labels = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};

MapThread[Show[#1, PlotLabel -> "COVID-19 " <> #2] &, {plots, labels}] // 
  Partition[#, UpTo[2]] & //
  Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]